# Do I need to acquire wakelock to avoid CPU sleep when serverSocket listens for Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-wake-lock

I have used Android Bluetooth chat sample in my application.My BluetoothChatService(with AcceptThread and ConnectedThread) started from my MainActivity onCreate() and stopped onDestroy().

1. So AcceptThread and ConnectedThread listens forever.When mobile CPU goes to sleep,these threads will run or stop listening?
2. Shall I need to acquire wakelock to keep these threads active,or already it wakes when client connects?
3. If I need to use wakelock,acquire on onCreate of MainActivity is enough or shall i need to acquire wakelock for AccceptThread and ConnectedThread separately?

Comment: any answers will be appreciated

Comment: Have tested it? Do you receive chat messages while CPU is sleeping? I assume that you don't.